# Question regarding the proof of $f^{−1 }(Y \setminus C) = X \setminus f^{−1 }(C)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I have a question which says the following:
Let: $f: X \to Y$ be a function, and assume that $C \subset Y$. Show that
$f^{-1}(Y \setminus C) =  X \setminus f^{-1}(C)$

I'm not too sure where to go with this question and I have a few more examples after this one which have a similar pattern. I'd really like if someone could show me how to solve these or direct me to some resources which have examples I could take a look at in order to try and solve a few myself. Thank you.

Comment: In the statement you want to show, $D$ does not appear at all. So, only $C \subseteq Y$ is needed, not $D$.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion, but $D$ is used for a follow on question to this one. I've amended my original post to get rid of the $D$ for now thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x\in f^{-1}(Y\setminus C)\implies f(x)\not\in C\implies x\not\in f^{-1}(C)$ i.e. $x\in X\setminus f^{-1}(C)$. Hence $f^{-1}(Y\setminus C)\subseteq X\setminus f^{-1}(C)$.

$x\in X\setminus f^{-1}(C)\implies f(x)\not\in C\implies f(x)\in Y\setminus C$ which means $x\in f^{-1}(Y\setminus C)$. Hence $f^{-1}(Y\setminus C)\supseteq X\setminus f^{-1}(C)$.